# `valueFormatter` not called in Enterprise

Tags: ag-grid

`valueFormatter` defined in `columnDefs` is not called in Enterprise but standard license.

Columns are defined as below:

```
{field:'StartDate', headerName:'Start Date', width: 100, valueFormatter: fromIsoDate}
```

If referenced Enterprise, it don't work

```
<script src="ag-grid/ag-grid-enterprise.js"></script>
```

But, following:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid@17.0.0/dist/ag-grid.min.js"></script>
```

Version: 17.0

Comment: could you please explain more in detail? or put some code?

Answer (score 0):

Using library [from this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ag-grid/ag-grid-enterprise/master/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js) source fixed the issue.